# uitableview delete rows

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //add code here for when you hit delete

    Budget *deletedBudget = (Budget *)[self.budgetList objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.context deleteObject:deletedBudget];

    NSError* error;
    if(![self.context  save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
        if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
            for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
                NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@" something wierd happens ... hmmm");

        }
    }else {
        NSLog(@"budget deleted!!!! YEEEEE");
    }



    [self updateBugetList];
       [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if ([self.budgetList.fetchedObjects count] >= 1) {

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

    if ([self.budgetList.fetchedObjects count] == 0) {
        //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
    }


    [self.tableView endUpdates];




}
```

This code works for most rows but not for the last row.

when the delete for the last row is tapped the log message that the entity is deleted display, but the row is not removed from the table view ...

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

How can this be avoided ?

Answer (score 0):

I confused a little bit by this condition:

```
    if ([self.budgetList.fetchedObjects count] >= 1) {
...

        if ([self.budgetList.fetchedObjects count] == 0) {
...            
         [tableView reloadData];
        }
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
```

Seems you never get update the table, because second condition will not run.
I think you should reload table always in this case

Comment: well the thing is ... after I delete all the row , except one... I need to delete the section.. no???? That's where the problem is ... the last row still shows after it's data is deleted from core data and the fetchedResults controller updated ...